# Uncaught SyntaxError- Unexpected token + 1 more

Tags: angular, npm, syntax-error, seed

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to run a seed-project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 Seed [using RC4] - Minimalistic TypeScript starter project</title>
        <base href="." />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

        <!-- @exclude -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor/coresheet.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css" />

        <script src="src/vendor/node_modules/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="src/vendor/node_modules/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="src/vendor/node_modules/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="src/vendor/node_modules/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>

        <script src="app/system.conf.js"></script>
        <!-- @endexclude -->

        <!-- @include dist.head.html -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <app>Loading...</app>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { IsRouteActive } from './pipes/is-route-active.pipe';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { PRECOMPILE_COMPONENTS } from './routes';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'src/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['styles/components/app.css'],
    providers: [],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: [IsRouteActive],
    precompile: PRECOMPILE_COMPONENTS
})

export class AppComponent {
    isUserAuthorized: boolean = false;

    constructor(private _router: Router, private _authService: AuthService) {
        this._router.events.subscribe(() => {
            this.isUserAuthorized = this._authService.isUserAuthorized();
        });
    }

    logout() {
        this._authService.logout();
        this._router.navigateByUrl('/');
    }
}
```

**system.conf.js:**

```
System.config({
    baseURL: './',
    map: {
        '@angular': 'src/vendor/node_modules/@angular',
        'rxjs': 'src/vendor/node_modules/rxjs'
    },
    packages: {
        'src': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/common': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/compiler': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/core': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/http': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/platform-browser': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        '@angular/router': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'rxjs': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});

System.import('./src/bootstrap.js').catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Here is the [seed-project](https://github.com/matthias-schuetz/angular2-seed)

**The errors are(after npm start)**

> system.conf.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:8080/src/vendor/node_modules/Reflect.js.map

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: Anyone?! I Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seed-project is not setup to run using npm start command.

You will have to follow below steps-

Step1: Run below commands to install all dependencies.

```
npm install typings -g
npm install
typings install
```

Step2: You need to run gulp command

```
gulp start:dev
```

Run your application from `http://localhost:8080/`

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

In Chrome, Open Developer tools > Settings > Preferences > Sources
Disable checkbox of 'Enable JavaScript source maps' and refresh http://localhost:8080/

[image]

Comment: @Miss.Code If you are using latest chrome version, you need to follow settings steps. Please check my EDIT in above answer.
I have verified this in Chrome as well as on firefox and I able to run seed project without any error.

Comment: @Miss.Code if your map error issue is resolved then mark answer as useful and post syntax error issue.

Comment: The syntax error is the main part of Q. What do you mean by "post it" ?!

Comment: Are you following steps correctly? I didn't get any syntax error.